# Terraform: Pause creation of next instance of a resources

Tags: terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

I have a null_resource resource to attach usage plan to api gateway in terraform with this configuration:

This will attach the same usage plan to multiple api gateways

```
resource "null_resource" "usage_plan_attach" {
  count = 4
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # Run the script to attach this API to Usage Plan tiers.
    command = "apigw-usageplan --api_id ${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.apigw[count.index].id} --stage ${aws_api_gateway_stage.stage[count.index].stage_name} --usage_plans ${jsonencode(var.api_gateway_usage_plans)}"
  }

  triggers = {
    build_number = timestamp()
  }
}
```

This is failing because of the limit on the number of `UpdateUsagePlan` requests (1 every 20 seconds). Is there any alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would like to recommend you to use the terraform resource to upload the usage plan.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "example" {
  name         = "my-usage-plan"
  description  = "my description"
  product_code = "MYCODE"

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_stage.development.stage_name
  }

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.example.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_stage.production.stage_name
  }

  quota_settings {
    limit  = 20
    offset = 2
    period = "WEEK"
  }

  throttle_settings {
    burst_limit = 5
    rate_limit  = 10
  }
}
```

Official reference: [api_gateway_usage_plan](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_usage_plan)

Now, if it is impossible to use the terraform resource for some reason and you must run a local-exec, you could try to add "sleep" before the command, for example:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
    sleep_time=22
    sleep_index=$((${count.index}+1))
    sleep_total=$(($sleep_time*$sleep_index))
    sleep $sleep_total
    **Your code here***
    EOT
  }
```

I broke the variables above to make it easier to understand.

Set a base sleep time to 22 seconds (above 20).

Set index to the count.index and add 1 because the first index is 0.

Multiply both of them.

Sleep before running your code.

This way, it will always add additional 22 seconds sleep compared to the previous count.